# Python UTF-8 encoding wrong representation

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

I'm using python 2.7.X. I load some XML and the XML is utf-8 encoded. So I do the following:

```
def get_xml(self):
    r = requests.get("https://dataserver.com")
    xml = r.text
    return xml.encode("utf-8")

def parse_xml(xml):
    tree = ET.fromstring(xml)
    for child in tree:
        print "    Raw type = " + str(type(child.attrib["name"]))
        print "Encoded type = " + str(type(child.attrib["name"].encode("utf-8")))
        print child.attrib["name"].encode("utf-8")
        print str(child.attrib["name"])
        print "------------"
```

This results in the following error:

```
    Raw type = <type 'unicode'>
Encoded type = <type 'str'>
MalmÃ¶ FF - Paris SG
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 4-5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

So, the `UnicodeEncodeError`is clear to me. However, after having encoded the `unicode`string as a `utf-8`string I would expect it to be correctly represented. That is, the `MalmÃ¶ FF` should actually be `Malmö FF`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I think your expression `str(child.attrib["name"])` will use the standard encoding to encode the unicode. Are you sure this is set to utf-8? My guess is you have it set on latin-1 or something else. Try rewriting it to `child.attrib["name"].encode("utf-8")`.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. However, I'm 100% sure it is UTF-8. Also `print "Latin-1 Encoded type = " + str(type(child.attrib["name"].encode("latin-1")))` result in an error.

Comment: You don't need to cast to `str` when you have already encoded something. It will be a string of bytes with a certain encoding. I would still recommend you to try my suggested rewrite, just to be sure.

Comment: Are you sure your suggestion does not contain a typo? You suggest `child.attrib["name"].encode("utf-8")`. I already do this

Comment: Okay, you are right. It is indeed `latin-1` encoded. That is weird because the xml encoding is explicitly set to `utf-8`

Comment: I mean your fourth `print` in the `for child in tree` loop. It is not encoded and will be in unicode until you cast `str` and then python will try to encode it to whatever encoding is the default one. In your case latin-1.

Comment: The xml encoding is indeed utf-8 but this tells python how to **decode** the xml into unicode. This works, because you end up with unicode. What doesn't work is when you encode again, to write to stdout.

Comment: Hmm, I would think that I could choose the encoding if a string is represented in utf-8. So if the original xml is indeed utf-8 and then python converts it to unicode, where does the latin-1 then come from???

Comment: Try adding `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` to the top of your .py file. This sets the standard encoding to utf-8.
Here is a great guide to unicode and encodings in python, I suggest you read it: http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/

Comment: Actually I added this line to the top of my python file. I checked that it has no typo in it

Comment: @kakben that's only necessary if your source code has UTF-8 (or non-ASCII) in it. It does not need to be set if you're handling UTF-8

Comment: @kakben, `#coding:utf8`  does not set the standard encoding to UTF-8.  It declares the encoding on the source file only, and has no effect if there are only ASCII characters in the source file.

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack and Mark Tolonen thank you for pointing this out for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of issues:

1. You're either on Windows or sshing to a Unix box with the incorrect terminal emulation. Your terminal is incorrectly converting a multi-byte UTF-8 character into two ISO-8895-* characters:

   `MalmÃ¶` in Windows-1252/ISO-8895-* = `Malm\xc3\xb6` = `Malmö` in UTF-8.
2. If you're on Windows, don't print UTF-8 to the console. Use this: https://github.com/Drekin/win-unicode-console
3. Do not encode prior to printing. Let Python do it for you. If Python complains and you're on Unix, ensure your locale is set to a UTF-8 version, e.g. `en_US.UTF-8`. If all else fails, set `PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8` in your environment
4. Do not convert Unicode objects to str objects unless your really must. If you do, use the `.encode("utf-8")` rather than `str()` (they both result is `str` objects) to ensure a suitable encoding is used. But again - don't do it.
5. If you need to Unicode objects to a file, use:

   ```
   my_f = io.open("myfile.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")
   my_f.write(my_unicode_object)
   ```

   The Unicode object will be be encoded for you.

Comment: Thanks for these points. FYI: I'm using Mac OS X Yosemite with the standard Apple terminal application. My locales are all set to something that contains `UTF-8`. I still do not understand why these strings are encoded in latin-1 ?

Comment: The Apple terminal has an emulation setting. It should be set to UTF-8 but may have got changed. Goto "Preferences" -> "Profiles" -> "Advanced". Remember to stop calling `.encode()` and `str()` as well.

Comment: Hmm, the terminal is and was set to UTF-8

Comment: I can replicate `MalmÃ¶` if I set my emulation incorrectly to "Windows-1252". Does it still do it if you remove the `.encode()` ?

Comment: Well, my terminal is set to UTF-8 and the ouput of `print "Without str() or encoding(...): " + child.attrib["name"]` is `Without str() or encoding(...): MalmÃ¶ FF - Paris SG`